# Format NSDate from string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have some trouble to convert this string :

```
@"15/08/2014 08:30"
```

Into an NSDate, here my code :

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];
```

When I print out [formatter dateFromString:fullDatesString]; (fullDatesString is my string) the result is :

```
2014-08-15 06:30:00 +0000
```

Why my time is less than 2 hours between my string and my NSDate object ?

Comment: Because `NSLog()` is not aware of time zones. Don't worry, your date object is constructed correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you print the description of the `NSDate`, it prints in in `GMT (+0000)` regardless of what timezone you or the NSDate is in.

If you convert that time to your timezone (GMT + 2 I assume), then the time is correct.

Comment: I thought that TimeZone has been correctly initialized by using [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

Comment: It is, but NSLog doesn't take it into account.